# How do I write to a memory-mapped address in Rust?

Tags: rust, embedded, mmap

I'm trying to make "Blinky" for STM32F1xx in Rust.
I know that there are libs for it, but I want to make my own "lib" for learning purposes.

I can access STM32's "registers" by their addresses like this in C:

```c
*(uint32_t*)(0x40021000 + 0x018) |= 0x10;
*(uint32_t*)(0x40011000 + 0x004) |= 0x33;
*(uint32_t*)(0x40011000 + 0x004) &= ~0xCC;
*(uint32_t*)(0x40011000 + 0x10) |= 0x300;

while(1) {}
```

This writes some bits to the `RCC_APB2ENR` register to enable clocking of port C, configures pins and enables LEDs on my Discovery.

I need to re-write this it in Rust, to make consts, fns and start writing nice Rusty code. Is it possible in Rust without FFI calling C code? Can I achieve this with the `asm!` macro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C you should declare your pointers as `volatile` when accessing hardware registers, so that the compiler does the accesses exactly as you program them. Otherwise it could reorder them or eliminate duplicate accesses to the same register.

Since Rust 1.9 (thanks to this [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1467)) you can use `core::ptr::read_volatile` and `core::ptr::write_volatile` to read and write to such memory.

If you have an older version of Rust, these are available as `volatile_read` and `volatile_store` in [core::intrinsics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/), which however are permanently unstable, and thus require a nightly version of Rust to access them.

Comment: Does the compiler's behaviour for non-volatile pointers is the same for C and Rust?

Comment: Yes, the Rust compiler can do the same optimizations. The LLVM backend that does this is used for both languages.

Answer (score 10):

The functions [`read_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html) and [`write_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.write_volatile.html) are stable since version 1.9, so you should be using these. Borrowing @ker's translated sample for demonstration:

```
use std::ptr::{read_volatile, write_volatile};

const A: *mut u32 = (0x40021000 + 0x018) as *mut u32;
const B: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x004) as *mut u32;
const C: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x10) as *mut u32;
unsafe {
    write_volatile(A, read_volatile(A) | 0x10);
    write_volatile(B, read_volatile(B) | 0x33);
    write_volatile(B, read_volatile(B) & !0xCC);
    write_volatile(C, read_volatile(C) | 0x300);
}
```

Furthermore, the [`volatile`](https://crates.io/crates/volatile) crate provides wrapper types around values for volatile access.

```
use std::ptr::NonNull;

use volatile::VolatilePtr; // 0.5

const A: *mut u32 = (0x40021000 + 0x018) as *mut u32;
const B: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x004) as *mut u32;
const C: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x10) as *mut u32;


unsafe {
    let volatile_a = VolatilePtr::new(NonNull::new_unchecked(A));
    let volatile_b = VolatilePtr::new(NonNull::new_unchecked(B));
    let volatile_c = VolatilePtr::new(NonNull::new_unchecked(C));

    volatile_a.update(|x| x | 0x10);
    volatile_b.update(|x| x & !0xCC);
    volatile_c.update(|x| x | 0x300);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

rust has the [`std::ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/index.html) module in the standard library. It offers functions like [`ptr::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html) and [`ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html) which are much more explicit than dereferencing.

So your example would be

```
const A: *mut u32 = (0x40021000 + 0x018) as *mut u32;
const B: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x004) as *mut u32;
const C: *mut u32 = (0x40011000 + 0x10) as *mut u32;
unsafe {
    ptr::write(A, ptr::read(A) | 0x10);
    ptr::write(B, ptr::read(B) | 0x33);
    ptr::write(B, ptr::read(B) & !0xCC);
    ptr::write(C, ptr::read(C) | 0x300);
}
```

The more concise version is to use dereferencing, but that only works for `Copy` types:

```
*A |= 0x10;
*B |= 0x33;
*B &= !0xCC;
*C |= 0x300;
```