# How do I ensure memory accesses to a memory-mapped peripheral are volatile?

Tags: rust

In embedded programming, a memory-mapped peripheral can be accessed through a structure placed at the correct address. How do I ensure memory accesses to the peripheral are indeed performed on the bus in Rust? In C, this would be done by making the variable or fields `volatile`.

Consider this example:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Periph {
    sr: u32, /* Status  */
    cr: u32, /* Control */
    dr: u32, /* Data    */
}

const PERIPH1: *mut Periph = 0x10001200 as *mut Periph;
const PERIPH2: *mut Periph = 0x10001400 as *mut Periph;

fn useperiph(p: &mut Periph) -> i32 {
    p.cr = CR_CONSTANT;
    if p.cr != CR_CONSTANT {
        /* Peripheral was not enabled */
        return -1;
    }

    /* Loop a few micro seconds until ready */
    while p.sr != SR_CONSTANT {}

    /* Write values to hardware FIFO */
    p.dr = DATA1;
    p.dr = DATA2;
    p.dr = DATA3;
    0
}
```

I need to ensure that the compiler won't remove the check on the control register, will leave all loads of the status register, and won't collapse the  three stores to the data register. How do I do that?

Comment: That is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35009015/1233251, except that the answer is outdated. I think I should make an updated answer there instead of replicating information here.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510388/1233251).

Answer (score 0):

The best I know how to do is to use something akin to the volatile_cell library from Zinc. The structure for the memory-mapped peripheral registers has `VolatileCell<u32>`-typed registers rather than plain `u32`. `VolatileCell` wraps a value, has the same size, and provides accessors which use `core::ptr::read_volatile` and `core::ptr::write_volatile`. Stripped down to its essentials, `VolatileCell` looks like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct VolatileCell<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> VolatileCell<T> {

    /// Get register value.
    #[inline]
    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        unsafe {
            read_volatile(&self.value)
        }
    }

    /// Set register value.
    #[inline]
    pub fn set(&self, value: T) {
        unsafe {
            write_volatile(&self.value as *const T as *mut T, value)
        }
    }
}
```

And then the peripheral register structure is written using `VolatileCell<u32>` fields:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Periph {
    sr: VolatileCell<u32>, /* Status  */
    cr: VolatileCell<u32>, /* Control */
    dr: VolatileCell<u32>, /* Data    */
}

const PERIPH1: *mut Periph = 0x10001200 as *mut Periph;
const PERIPH2: *mut Periph = 0x10001400 as *mut Periph;

fn useperiph(p: &mut Periph) -> i32 {
    p.cr.set(CR_CONSTANT);
    if p.cr.get() != CR_CONSTANT {
        /* Peripheral was not enabled */
        return -1;
    }

    /* Loop a few micro seconds until ready */
    while p.sr.get() != SR_CONSTANT {}

    p.dr.set(DATA1);
    p.dr.set(DATA2);
    p.dr.set(DATA3);
    0
}
```

The resulting code has the correct semantics, and is only slightly more verbose than using `u32` directly. Being explicit is arguably an upside.